# Formula to Find All Possible Variations

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I've been trying to solve a coding problem for several days now and I'm fairly stuck and I'll blame this on my inferior knowledge of math.  I've been trying to do this by iterating over each number, finding the differences, and listing each iteration; however, this is proving to be incredibly complicated as well as non-performant.

> Given a monotonic array of numbers, count the number of variations that can exist between these numbers where the distance can be 1, 2, or 3.

So if I have a list of numbers:

```
   1,  2,  3,  4,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
  14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 28,
  31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 42, 45,
  46, 47, 48, 49
```

If I were to list out each number that can have a variation and the distance between it and the next number I would get a list like:

```
// num => paths: [...distance to next number]
  1 => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  2 => [ 1, 2 ],
  7 => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  8 => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  9 => [ 1, 2 ],
  17 => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  18 => [ 1, 2 ],
  23 => [ 1, 2 ],
  31 => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  32 => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  33 => [ 1, 2 ],
  45 => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  46 => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  47 => [ 1, 2 ]
```

I'm fairly certain there is a way that I can use the list above to grab the different variations that would exist.  An example of a particular variation would be:
`1,4,7,10,11,14,17,19,20,23,25,28,31,34,35,38,39,42,45,48,49`

A couple of other takeaways:

1. The order of the numbers must remain in a `monotonic` pattern.
2. I know that this particular list has a possible of number of variations of `19208`.
3. The distance between one number and the next cannot be greater than `3`

Comment: It looks like what you are looking for is "subset" rather than "permutation"

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  A permutation of a list of numbers is a list of the same numbers, you only change the order of the numbers, so you need to review your definitions and edit your question

Comment: thnx for that.  I've updated the post to replace the term with something more generic as my knowledge of math pretty much stops dead at `y=mx+b`.  Feel free to let me know if there is anything else I need to clarify :)

Comment: Does the list "2,3" count as a valid "variation"?

Comment: Your `num => paths` data is quite mysterious to me. Why is there a gap from 23 to 31, for instance? That data is part of the input specifying the question? Must your final lists include 1 and 49? Giving a complete example in a small case would probably help. I'd be shocked if the correct approach to whatever the question really is weren't ultimately recursion.

Comment: It looks like if I count the total number of subsets where the first number is either $1,2,3$ and the last number is $49$ then I get the number $19208$. However not sure if this is just a coincidence. If I restrict the first number to $1$ it's way less than $19208$ and if I don't restrict the last number to $49$ then it's way more than $19208$.

Comment: It's as if there is an extra $0$ at the beginning and $0$ and $49$ must be included.

Comment: They do provide a smaller set: `1,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19`.  Which I am told the answer is 8.  The problem is that I can either add (1+3)*2 or 1+3+2+2 to get to get to 8 and neither of of those solutions seem to work for the larger example :/.  The paths are defined as `4 => [ 1, 2, 3 ], 5 => [ 1, 2 ], 10 => [ 1, 2 ]`

Comment: The first number must be 1 and last number must be included in the second case confirmed. I will post my code as an answer that assumes the first number must be at most $3$ and the last number must be included.

Comment: @cr001 is correct to assume that the first number will be 1 and the last number will need to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the question has an extra condition that the first number must be less than or equal to $3$ and the last number must be the largest number in the set, based on the two test cases given with results $19208$ and $8$,

Here's how you find the number:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int num = 0;
void traverse(int* list, int size, int i) {
    if(i >= size) {
        return;
    }

    if(i == size - 1) {
        num ++;
        return;
    }
    if(i <= size - 2 && list[i+1] - list[i] <= 3) {
        traverse(list,size,i+1);
    }
    if(i <= size - 3 && list[i+2] - list[i] <= 3) {
        traverse(list,size,i+2);
    }
    if(i <= size - 4 && list[i+3] - list[i] <= 3) {
        traverse(list,size,i+3);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]= {1,  2,  3,  4,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
  14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 28,
  31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 42, 45,
  46, 47, 48, 49};
    int size = 31;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        if(arr[i] > 3) break;
        traverse(arr,size,i);
    }
    cout << num;
    return 0;
}
```

You can paste it here and test (modify the arr and size parts to change the array): https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

DP-optimized way of the above algorithm (In order to deal with the "first number must be less than or equal to three" constraint you will need to add a zero at the beginning of the array and increase size by 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[]= {0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
  14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 28,
  31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 42, 45,
  46, 47, 48, 49};
    int size = 32;
  
    int* nums = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        nums[i] = 0;
   }
    nums[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        if(i >= 3 && arr[i] - arr[i - 3] <= 3) {
            nums[i] += nums[i - 3];
        }
        if(i >= 2 && arr[i] - arr[i - 2] <= 3) {
            nums[i] += nums[i - 2];
        }
        if(i >= 1 && arr[i] - arr[i - 1] <= 3) {
            nums[i] += nums[i - 1];
        }
    }

    cout << nums[size - 1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to write pseudocode for a similar recursive solution.

Comment: It definitely works with the two smaller inputs but im currently 12 hours into waiting for it to churn out the result of the puzzle input which has 99 numbers. `yikes.exe`

Comment: @object Object Every recursive algorithm has a corresponding Dynamic Programming optimization. If you are dealing with large arrays you should consider rewrite the recursive logic using DP. I have included that in the bottom of answer.